# How to turn Visual Studio XAML validation errors into build errors?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I have WPF app and inside its XAML there are image paths:
[image]

If the paths are wrong Visual Studio shows errors. I want to get errors for invalid paths or other problems during the build. How do I achieve this?

Comment: I don't have a specific solution to this problem, but you may find relevant and useful ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350109/compile-time-checking-of-bindings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this today. The XAML parser (used by the XAML language service in Visual Studio's editor) is different than the one used to compile the XAML.